# Macro para eliminar datos de Columna?

Tags: vba

Tengo una macro para eliminar con la condición de un Nombre un numero de Filas en A ejemplo PEPE en A50 que tiene unos datos en A51:A55 y elimina todos los PEPE A.50:A55,Pero necesitaría todo lo contrario….. una Macro que en Columna A Eliminase todo los datos menos PEPE con sus datos ejemplo A50:A51 que esta repetido X veces en A en diferentes posiciones en A.

```
Sub EliminarFilas_segun_texto ()
    Dim Texto As String, Celda As Range, Hoja As Worksheet
    Set Hoja = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOJA")
    Texto = InputBox("Texto a buscar")
    If Not Texto = "" Then
        For cont = Hoja.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
           Set Celda = Hoja.Columns("A").Find(Texto, , , xlWhole)
           If Not Celda Is Nothing Then
              Hoja.Range(Celda, Celda.Offset(24, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
           End If
        Next cont
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
Dim Hoja As Worksheet

Set Hoja = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For i = 50 To 1 Step -1
    If Hoja.Cells(i, 1) <> "PEPE" Then
        Hoja.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Lo mejor para eliminar filas es ir de más a menos. Es decir, empezar desde abajo hacia arriba y utilizar el parámetro "Step - 1" en el For.
Con esto recorres de la fila 50 a la 1 y eliminas todas aquellas filas cuya celda no contenga "PEPE".

Adáptalo a tus necesidades y verás que funciona.